# How to convert ieee754 doubles into fraction of two integers?

Tags: c, floating-point

How do I get `long long` (64-bit) values `a` and `b` from a `double` (64-bit) value `d` such that `(double)a / b` more or less equals `d`?  Is this possible (without loss of precision)?

I've tried along the lines of this but it didn't get anywhere so I'm thinking maybe I've got the wrong idea:

```
union ieee754_double u;
u.d = d;

long long a = (long long)u.ieee.mantissa0 << 32 | u.ieee.mantissa1;
long long b = (long long)1 << (u.ieee.exponent + IEEE754_DOUBLE_BIAS);
```

Comment: [Continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)

Comment: You need to add in the missing implicit leading 1 in the mantissa.

Comment: It is possible (and indeed easy) to find two integers `p` and `q` such that the ratio between them exactly equals a double (well except for NaN and infinities). But often one of them would be longer than 64 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments, some of the other answers and pure trail and error, I came up with this (which seems to more or less work):

```
union ieee754_double u;
u.d = d;

long long a = (long long)(!u.ieee.exponent && u.ieee.exponent != 0x7ff) << 52 |
        (long long)u.ieee.mantissa0 << 32 | u.ieee.mantissa1;
int exp = IEEE754_DOUBLE_BIAS - u.ieee.exponent + 52;

long long b;
if (u.ieee.exponent != 0x7ff) {
    if (exp > 62) {
        a >>= exp - 62;
        exp = 62;
    }
    if (exp < 0) {
        a <<= 0 - exp;
        exp = 0;
    }
    b = 1LL << exp;
} else {
    b = 0;
}

a = u.ieee.negative ? -a : a;
```

I'm still trying to figure out where the edges are, but since I'm shifting out bits, I *think* it's lossless up to `+/-2**62` and down to `2**-10`

Doing some round-trip tests with `atof(argv[1])` --> `printf()`), I seems to be able to reproduce values exactly up to `+/-2**53` and down to `2**-18` (so long as I round).  I'm guessing the `2**53` is a limitation of `double` though.

Answer (score 6):

Every floating-point number, except for infinities and NaN, can be exactly represented as a ratio of two integers. Some double-precision floats do require integers wider than 64 bits — for example, `1e-300` would convert to `6032057205060441 / (2 ** 1049)`. However, floats inside the approximate range `(2**-40, 2**63)` can be losslessly converted to a fraction of two 64-bit integers.

One example of such a conversion function is in Python's [`as_integer_ratio()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6b409ab596db/Objects/floatobject.c#l1698) method on its float objects. Translated from Python/C-ese, the code looks like this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void double_as_ratio(double flt, long long *numerator, long long *denominator)
{
    double float_part;
    int exponent;
    long long long_exponent;
    int i;

    float_part = frexp(flt, &exponent);  /* flt == float_part * 2**exponent exactly */
    for (i=0; i<300 && float_part != floor(float_part) ; i++) {
        float_part *= 2.0;
        exponent--;
    }
    /* flt == float_part * 2**exponent exactly and float_part is integral. */

    *numerator = (long long) float_part;           /* can overflow */
    long_exponent = 1LL << labs((long) exponent);  /* can overflow */
    if (exponent > 0) {
        *numerator *= long_exponent;
        *denominator = 1;
    }
    else
        *denominator = long_exponent;
}
```

This code doesn't rely on the exact layout of the bits, and only depends on the `frexp` and `floor` functions required by C89. Applied to the floating-point value `0.1`, it produces the correct values of `3602879701896397` and `36028797018963968`.

Comment: This answer is completely correct and reminds me of the balloon joke :-)

Comment: @Ben: No, it's not completely correct.  `i` needs to go up to 1076 or so to handle subnormals correctly.  There are numerous other problems, like the overflow noted.  I'd also point out that, apart from the subnormal case, `double`s are perfectly capable of representing the relevant numerator and denominator.  You don't need arbitrary-precision aruthmetic at all.

Comment: @tmyklebu Does it really need to handle subnormals? Python seems to get by without it. The overflow issue can be corrected by using bigints (using doubles seems circular), but the OP explicitly requested `long long`.

Comment: The answer is wrong, whether or not denormalised numbers are allowed. (Also, what's the balloon joke?) The largest positive float that can't be represented as a ratio of 64-bit integers is 0xFFFFFF/2**64, which is about 2**-40. This is much bigger than 2**-63.

Comment: @TonyK Fixed the incorrect range claim. No idea about the balloon joke.

Comment: @user4815162342: Using doubles isn't circular at all.  They're a perfectly good representation for integers when you only need the most significant 53 bits.  Your code doesn't even handle doulbes where the exponent is less than -300.

Comment: @tmyklebu Can you give a concrete example of a double that doesn't work, excepting subnormals? If there are such, I'd like to report a Python bug. As far as I can tell, the code works with exponents less than -300 just fine (except for the noted overflow when casting to long long, which would indeed be fixed by just using `double`). Since `frexp` returns a normalized fraction whose absolute value is in `[0.5, 1)`, the number of doublings shouldn't reach anywhere near 300. (I suspect the limit is a sanity check for buggy implementations of `frexp` or to cater to exotic non-IEEE754 platforms.)

Comment: @user4815162342: Ick.  No, actually, I can't.  It does work fine, even for subnormals, very small normals, and very large numbers.  (I mangled the renormalisation of `numerator` and `denominator` at the end when testing your code earlier and concluded that the problem was not where it actually was.  And you do need slightly more range for the denominator.  Not just for subnormals, but even for very small normal numbers.)

Comment: @user4815162342 Can you please explain the reasoning behind the magic number 300 in this instance? The Python source code seems to suggest that is for the almost-never case where the radix is not 2.

Comment: @oda Unfortunately I can't. You might want to ask on python-dev or other forum frequented by Python core devs.

Comment: @user4815162342 No worries. I will need to investigate this. FWIW I would have also referenced the Python implementation to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying to do? If you are converting `double` to a rational, you almost certainly want an approximate answer.

How accurate do you want it to be? If the answer was exactly 244653797/159601597, would you want that to be the answer? I very much doubt it. Do you want to prefer decimal fractions? Or fractions with small-number denominators? Or what?

Should 0.4286 come up as 4286/10000 = 2143/500 or 1/7?

Should 0.428 come up as 107/250 or 1/7?

Without knowing what problem you are actually trying to solve, it is very hard to solve it.

Comment: Note that the denominator of a floating-point number is always a power of 2, so `244653797/159601597` cannot be the exact answer.

Comment: @user4815162342, good point :-), but I am nevertheless sure that he wants `1.0f / 7.0f` to resolve back to 1/7.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't see that in the question (and it's impossible to boot). The OP explicitly states that the starting point is a 64-bit float, and that a fraction whose value corresponds to the float ("more or less") is the desired output. There is no indication as to how the float was obtained.

Answer (score 1):

Dan Steffy wrote [code for rational reconstruction](https://files.oakland.edu/users/steffy/web/reconstruct/) that's quite simple and instructive to read.  If you want `a` and `b` so that `a/b` rounds to the correct `double` and `b` is reasonably small, set the `bits` parameter when calling `reconstruct_bits` to 53.

I believe the code works by continued fraction approximation.  It's prudent to note that this doesn't necessarily produce **the** best rational approximation for a given denominator bound or relative error bound.  It produces all of the rational reconstructions that minimise a related quantity (which presently eludes me) for all possible denominator bounds.